# Laravel logout

Tags: laravel

На сайте имеется авторизация + запоминание по токену, что-то не могу разыскать нигде решения логаута на всех устройствах конкретного пользователя.

Comment: @avengerweb, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//для текущего
Auth::logout();
//для заданного id
User::find(id)->logout();
```